# How to get Input Value from masterpage

Tags: c#, master-pages

how can i get the value of input control from masterpage ?

my master page:

```
.......
 <div class="searchform">
          <form id="formsearch" name="formsearch" method="post" action="#">
            <span>
            <input name="editbox_search" class="editbox_search" id="editbox_search" maxlength="80" value="Code Client:" type="text" />
            </span>
            <input name="button_search" src="images/search_btn.gif" class="button_search" type="image" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content_resize"> 
      <div class="mainbar">
        <div class="article">

               <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
      </div>
.....
```

and my default.aspx that use MasterPAge:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label ClientId = (Label)Master.FindControl("editbox_search");

    ASPxLabel_Err.Text = ClientId.Text;
}
```

i try to convert input Control into Label, because i can not find input control.

but i got nullReference that logic because i can not convert input control into label control.

Comment: You need to make it `runat=server` or use a `TextBox`. But it would not hardlink the page with the master, you could provide a public property `CodeClient` in your master which gets/sets simply the value of this control. Then you can access it by casting the `Master` property to the actual type: `((MyMaster)Master).CodeClient = "new code client"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var editbox = (HtmlInputControl)Master.FindControl("editbox_search");
Response.Write (editbox.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     var mastertxt = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText)Master.FindControl("ctl00$editbox_search");
     ASPxLabel_Err.Text = mastertxt.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to make this tag as "runat= server" then only you can use:

var txtEditBox =(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText)this.Page.Master.FindControl("editbox_search");

ASPxLabel_Err.Text = txtEditBox.Value ;